# okHttp3 newCall's parameter mismatch type request

Tags: android-studio, request, okhttp

okHttpClient?.newCall(request)?.enqueue(object: Callback{

Is used in "request"

Type mismatch.
Required: Request!
Found: Request.Builder

Is displayed.

Even if I look for sample codes, it seems to be the right expression, but I want to know how to solve it.

```
fun sendMessage(destinationUid: String, title: String, message: String) {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("pushtokens").document(destinationUid).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                var token = task?.result?.get("pushToken").toString()

                var pushDTO = PushDTO()

                pushDTO.to = token
                pushDTO.notification.title = title
                pushDTO.notification.body = message

                var body = RequestBody.create(JSON, gson?.toJson(pushDTO))
                var request = Request.Builder()
                Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + serverKey)
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build()

                okHttpClient?.newCall(request)?.enqueue(object : Callback{
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {

                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                        println(response?.body()?.string())
                    }

                })


            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var request = Request.Builder()
            Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + serverKey)
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build()
```

Solved the problem.
Request.Builder()
This part was written twice and an error occurred.